# remove "?" from all anchor text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the `?` character from all anchor `href` values with Javascript. For example, there are many URLs like this:

```
<a href="https://example.com/something/?">my anchor</a>
```

I tried this but getting the error `index of is not a function`

```
var url = jQuery("a");
var a = url.indexOf("?");
var b =  url.substring(a);
var c = url.replace(b,"");
url = c;
```

Comment: `url` is a jquery object representing an anchor element. Use `url[0].href` instead, or `url.attr('href', ...)`

Comment: jQuery("a") return an element not a String, element doesn't have indexOf method that's why you get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can provide a function to `prop()` which runs against all elements in the collection. In the function you can accept the current `href` value as an argument then use `replace()` to remove the `?` characters:

```js
$('a').prop('href', (i, h) => h.replace(/\?/g, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com/something/?">my anchor 1</a>
<a href="https://example.com/somethingelse/?">my anchor 2</a>
<a href="https://example.com/?something">my anchor 2</a>
```

Note that this will replace all instances of `?` from *anywhere* in the `href` value. If you only want to remove it from the end of the string change the regex to `/\?$/g`

Comment: Why `prop` over `attr`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox for me, performance mainly, but this excellent answer covers the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/519413

Comment: I had an SO answer dowvoted because I (correctly) used .attr - downvoter said their senior dev had told them "just always use .prop"  *facepalm*

Comment: I would say generally use `prop()` over `attr()`, but `attr()` still has its place - for example `prop('href')` wil return the root URL, whereas `attr('href')` will return just the relative path in the HTML. In the case above it doesn't make a difference as the OP was using the full URL already.